# Using props.children and styled-component "as" prop with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I've looked through several existing solutions and posts and couldn't really find any solution.

So, I'm using React with Typescript and styled-component.

One part of my project is the `Heading` component. Ideally, I imagined to used it like `<Heading level={2}>Hello world!</Heading>` wherever I need it.

[Here is the simplified Codesandbox Code of it](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-hopper-kgy7k?file=/src/HeadingStyle.ts)

However, the `<S.Heading` throws Errors in my Linter, even though it seems to work visually speaking.

**Error**

> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2745)
>
> No overload matches this call.
> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2769)

Not sure what's wrong about my code since I think I followed most recommendations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) are not as smart as you might think.  You might expect `h${props.level}` to evaluate to a union type `"h1" | "h2" | ...` based on the type of your `props.level` variable.  Instead it is just `string`.  So you will need an `as` assertion somewhere in your code in order to declare that this `string` is a valid key of `JSX.IntrinsicElements`.

Getting the union `"h1" | "h2" | ...` as a type is tough because `Props['level']` is a union of `number` literals rather than `string` literals.  But we don't really need the union because t doesn't really matter which heading type it is.  You can use `as "h1"` and you'll be fine.

```
export default function Heading(props: Props) {
  return <S.Heading as={`h${props.level}` as "h1"}>{props.children}</S.Heading>;
}
```

---

Out of curiosity I wanted to see if I could extract the valid `h*` tags from `JSX.IntrinsicElements`.  I came up with a solution that *almost* works based on string length, but I forgot about `hr`!

```
type HTag = {
    [K in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]: K extends `h${string}${infer B}` ? B extends "" ? K : never : never
}[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]
```

evaluates to:

```
"h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "hr"
```

Comment: `as const` would do the job as well

Comment: @AlekseyL. your `as const`, where would you place that? And any resources regarding that?

@linda-paiste wow, you just blew my mind there. This seems like a super hacky approach which I didn't even know about. Also, your `as` for template literals isn't even documented on your reference link.

Comment: @Tanckom instead of `as "h1"`. `as const` will prevent type widening to `string`

Comment: And here's the link to docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#reverting-template-literal-inference

Comment: @AlekseyL. if you mean like this `<S.Heading as={`h${props.level}` as const}>{props.children}</S.Heading>` then it still gives me the same linting errors..

Comment: @Tanckom https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-leakey-rlhpx?file=/src/Heading.tsx